# Prove if $f(x)$ is a continuous function from reals to irrationals then it is constant

Tags: functions

Prove if $f(x)$ is a continuous function from reals to irrationals then it is constant.

In the first look it doesn't seem to be true because we can have two irrationals that are so close to each other and we can have that.But I don't know how to disprove that.

Comment: IVT${}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: ^ use the fact that the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What's that?

Comment: @TahaAkbari Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @Nilknarf How should I use it?

Comment: @TahaAkbari See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $f(\text{connected set}) = \text{connected set}$

Comment: Why is that true?

Comment: have you passed  Analysis, or topology course ? it is same as IVT..  @TahaAkbari

Comment: No I didn't but I know what IVT is.I got that thing no need to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is not constant. Then there are numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$ and that $f(a)\neq f(b)$. Let $q$ be a rational number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then, by the intermediate value theorem, there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=q$. But this is impossible, since $f(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I think you mean  "Let $q$ be a rational number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$".

Comment: @Ramiro RIght! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate value theorem states that if $f$ is continuous, then for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$, if $y\in \mathbb R$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ (inclusive), there exists $x$ in the interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=y$.

However, if $f:\mathbb R\to C(\mathbb Q)$, and there exist two distinct values of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ (such that $f(a)\ne f(b)$) then there exist some rational number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. However, if you choose $y$ to be a rational number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there does not exist $x\in R$ such that $f(x)=y$. Thus, for each $a,b\in \mathbb R$, $f(a)=f(b)$ and $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

- Suppose to the contrary that a continuous function $f: \mathbb R
     \rightarrow \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ is not constant. Then
  there exist $x,y \in \mathbb R$, $x \not = y$, such that $f(x) <
     f(y)$.
- By the density of rationals in the reals, since $f(x)$ and
  $f(y)$ are real numbers, there exists a $q \in \mathbb Q$ such that $f(x) < q < f(y)$.
- Since $f$ is continuous by assumption, by the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT, as previous commentors have referred to), there exists a $z \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(z) = q$. But this is a contradiction since $q \in \mathbb Q$ and cannot be in the range of $f$.
- Therefore, $f$ is constant. $\square$